# Pandas - appending data to dataframe lead to more rows than the file source has

Tags: python, pandas

I'm dealing with a situation here and I cannot tell what's the issue.

I have my source file which has two lines and looks as below:

```
Jul 26, 2021 12:12:12 AM CEST INFO, create test, execution-c9d549fc-7c1e-4f27-887c-bd3ab0dc21ec-2021.07.26, Create fake XML document, Preparing to collect data
Jul 26, 2021 1:12:12 PM CEST INFO, create test, execution-c9d549fc-7c1e-4f27-887c-bd3ab0dc21ec-2021.07.26, Create fake XML document, Preparing to collect data
```

I use the below code to load the file, read and append the source data to the dataframe:

```
data = []

months = (
    'Jan',
    'Feb',
    'Mar',
    'Apr',
    'May',
    'Jun',
    'Jul',
    'Aug',
    'Sep',
    'Sept',
    'Oct',
    'Nov',
    'Dec'
)

    for file in os.listdir():
        if file.endswith(dt.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d.log')):
            LogFile = r'path\test.2021_07_27.log'
    
            with open(LogFile, 'r') as f:
                for line in map(str.strip, f):
                    if not line or not line.startswith(months):
                        continue
                    line = line.split(maxsplit=6)
                    logdate = " ".join(line[:6])
                    logstatus = line[-1].split(maxsplit=1)[0]
                    loginfo = line[-1].split(maxsplit=1)[-1]
                    data.append({"LogDate": logdate, "LogStatus": logstatus, "LogInfo": loginfo})
    
                    tzmapping = {
                        'CEST': dateutil.tz.gettz('UTC'),
                    }
    
                    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
                    
                    print(df)
    
                    df['LogDate'] = df['LogDate'].apply(dateutil.parser.parse, ignoretz=True)
```

So far, so good (I guess). However, when I print the dataframe the result is displayed twice: once for the first row, including the column names appended and the second time, with both rows and also the column names:

```
                         LogDate LogStatus                                            LogInfo
0  Jul 26, 2021 12:12:12 AM CEST     INFO,  create test, execution-c9d549fc-7c1e-4f...
                         LogDate LogStatus                                            LogInfo
0  Jul 26, 2021 12:12:12 AM CEST     INFO,  create test, execution-c9d549fc-7c1e-4f...
1   Jul 26, 2021 1:12:12 PM CEST     INFO,  create test, execution-c9d549fc-7c1e-4f...
```

What am I missing here? Could you give me a hint what might be wrong with my code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `print(df)` you print a new `DataFrame` tha is created based on `data`.

However, `data` resides outside of your loop and can be considered as a global variable here. You append each line to `data` in each iteration.

Basically, you print all the processed line in each step, not just the current line.

Comment: Right. I had to take out the data from the `loop`.